# Adding two digits and finding their carry without IF and While

Tags: python-3.x, numbers

I want to add two three digit numbers, digit by digit, and need to get value of carry after addition without using IF/ELSE and While/For. For example, if I am adding 9 and 9, I need to get the carry of these numbers but without using IF/ELSE and WHILE/FOR. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question properly, I think you can achieve this with integer division.

For Example, the carry for 9 + 9 would be: `(9 + 9) // 10`. This would return 1.

For three digit numbers you can do: `(678 + 854) // 1000`.